# AMQP async listener starts listening to message only after an event happens

Tags: java, spring, amqp, event-listener, spring-amqp

I currently have an AMQP async listener that is listening to messages on a queue automatically.

However, my requirement is that I shouldn't have this listener listening to messages until a certain event has happened.  For event, I am thinking of using @EventListener annotation.

The async listener looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ExampleAmqpConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
        container.setQueueName("some.queue");
        container.setMessageListener(exampleListener());
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListener exampleListener() {
        return new MessageListener() {
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                System.out.println("received: " + message);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I was thinking of adding the @EventListener to the method messageListenerContainer() so it looks like this:

```
@Bean
@EventListener
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(CustomeEvent customEvent) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
    container.setQueueName("some.queue");
    container.setMessageListener(exampleListener());
    return container;
}
```

However, the messageListenerContainer() bean just seems to run at start up, regardless of the EventListener.

What is proper way for this async listner to listen to messages, only after a CustomEvent happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the containers `autoStartup` property to `false`.

In your `@EventListener`, auto wire the container and `start()` it.

**EDIT**

```
public class MyEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private SimpleMessageListenerContainer container;

    @EventListener
    public void someEvent(MyEvent event) {
        this.container.start();
    }

}
```

and

```
@Bean
public MyEventListener listener() {
    return new EventListener();
}
```

Comment: The first part makes sense; but in my case, does the autowiring happen in the class that publishes the event or in the class CustomeEvent?

Comment: You need a reference to the container in the event listener so you can execute the `start()` method. The publisher doesn't need to know anything about the container.

Comment: Sorry this may seem silly.  But I thought the EventListener annotation made messageListenerContainer() method a listener.  I thought that a class publishes CustomEvent, then using @EventListener, messageListenerContainer(CustomEvent customEvent) gets triggered by the event.  Therefore, messageListenerContainer() is the listener.  Is there a listener class that I need to create explicitly?

Comment: No `@EventListener` goes on a POJO method; see my edit. Adding the annotation to a bean definition like that means nothing. Beans are loaded at initialization time.